# How to call a class specific method in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm currently doing this

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validate :no_conflict

  private
  def no_conflict
    user.enrollments.where.not(id: self).each do |e|
      errors.add(:start_time, 'conflicts with another schedule') if true
    end
  end
end

class Availability < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validate :no_conflict

  private
  def no_conflict
    user.availabilities.where.not(id: self).each do |a|
      errors.add(:start_time, 'conflicts with another schedule') if true
    end
  end
end
```

Since there's identical code in both models I'm trying to move it to a concern like this

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  include Schedulize
end

class Availability < ApplicationRecord
  include Schedulize
end

module Schedulize
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    
  included do
    belongs_to :user
    validate :no_conflict
  end
    
  private
  def no_conflict
    user.<???>.where.not(id: self).each do |x|
      errors.add(:start_time, 'conflicts with another schedule') if true
    end
  end
end
```

I wasn't sure how to have the module call the class method that's including it (where the questions marks are above). Could someone help point me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def no_conflict
  user.send(self.class.table_name).where.not(id: self).each do |x|
    errors.add(:start_time, 'conflicts with another schedule') if true
  end
end
```

`self.class.table_name` will return `enrollments` & `availabilities` as per convention. If you have different names for the relationships in model & the table names, you can try something different.